# pandas to_sql enforced dtype for sqlite - incompatibility with unicode_literals

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

I run into a problem when wanting to save pandas dataframe to a sqlite database with specified the datatype. I have the following module.py:

```
# Import from future to make Python2 behave like Python3
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine=create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
cnx = engine.raw_connection()

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1', '1'] ,'col2': ['1.0', '1.2'],'col3': ['A', 'B']})

labels=['col1','col2','col3']
types=['TEXT','TEXT','TEXT']
mapping={k:v for k,v in zip(labels,types)}

df_out.to_sql(name='table',if_exists='replace',con=cnx,dtype=mapping)

df_in=pd.read_sql(sql='''SELECT * FROM "table" ''',con=cnx)
```

When I  run this code into a Python interpreter, I get the following error message `ValueError: col2 (TEXT) not a string`.

For what I discovered the incompatibility comes from the statement `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. When removing it, I get the expected behaviour : `df_in.dtypes` describing 3 columns of object type.

I tried to used raw strings `types=[r'TEXT',r'TEXT',r'TEXT']` but it did not change anything.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround.

Best regards,

Comment: So what exactly is the incompatibility problem? Any exceptions? Wrong output?

Comment: you right I added information to explain the incompatibility : `ValueError: col2 (TEXT) not a string`. Regards,

Comment: In Python 2, if you want to write `str` literals while using `unicode_literals`, use the `bytes` notation: `b'byte string literal'`. Raw strings have no effect on the type, they just change how backslashes are interpreted while Python parses the source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work fine. Could you promote it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, the future-import `unicode_literals` makes string literals behave like in Python 3.
That means a prefix-less string literal gives you a `unicode` string:

```
>>> type('foo')
<type 'unicode'>
```

If you want a legacy `str`, use a `b` prefix (because it corresponds to Python 3's `bytes` string):

```
>>> type(b'foo')
<type 'str'>
```

The `r` prefix doesn't affect the type. It only changes how the interpreter treats backslashes when parsing string literals in the source code:

```
>>> r'\foo'
u'\\foo'
>>> '\\foo'
u'\\foo'
```

It's just a different way of *writing* the literal, the same way you can write `1e-2` or `0.01` to get the same float value. From a string's *value* you can never tell if it was created through `r'...'` or `'...'` notation (or read from a file etc.).

You can combine the `r` prefix with the `b` prefix if you want to create a `str` with typing less backslashes:

```
>>> br'\foo'
'\\foo'
```

But that's not needed too often because of Python 2's automatic type coercion between `str` and `unicode`.